# ionViewWillEnter doesn't get Triggered -Ionic 5-Tabs

Tags: ionic5

I have 3 tabs in my app from which I want to redirect to another page.i.e when the user clicks on the tabs it will load a list from that I want to redirect to a page (say X).After clicking the back button of X page ionViewWillEnter/DidEnter doesnot work. Can any one help me to findout the solution ?

App Module Routing page :- Which loads a seprate module called UW.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'uw',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/UW/uw.module').then(m => m.UwModule)
  },
]
```

UW module Loads a dashboard page :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard-uw',
    loadChildren: () => import('src/app/UW/pages/dashboard-uw/dashboard-uw.module').then(m => m.DashboardUwPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard-uw',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
]
```

The dashboard page contain Tabs which loads seprate pages on each Tab click
Dashboard routing Module :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardUwPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: uwconstants.UW_TAB1,
        loadChildren: () => import('src/app/UW/pages/uw-premium/uw-premium.module').then(m => m.UwPremiumPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: uwconstants.UW_TAB2,
        loadChildren: () => import('src/app/UW/pages/uw-invoices/uw-invoices.module').then(m => m.UwInvoicesPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: uwconstants.UW_TAB3,
        loadChildren: () => import('src/app/UW/pages/uw-tat/uw-tat.module').then(m => m.UwTatPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: uwconstants.UW_TAB4,
        loadChildren: () => import('src/app/UW/pages/uw-intermediary/uw-intermediary.module').then(m => m.UwIntermediaryPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: uwconstants.UW_TAB5,
        loadChildren: () => import('src/app/UW/pages/uw-vet-pvet-add-tab/uw-vet-pvet-add-tab.module').then(m => m.UwVetPvetAddTabPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: uwconstants.UW_TAB1,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
    
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'uw/dashboard-uw/UW-TAB1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

];
```

Each tab click loads a seprate page,using this line of code

```
  public approvePremium(item) {
    this.navctrl.navigateForward([ '/uw/uw-premium-send', { leadCode: item } ])
  }
```

for back button click, I am using

```
 this.navctrl.navigateBack([ 'uw', 'dashboard-uw', 'UW-TAB1' ]);
```

ionViewWill Enter Not triggered after the back button click.Some one help me to findout the solution.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the tabs routing module by the following

### TabsPageRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'tab1',
            children: [ {
              path: '',
              loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule),
            },
            {
              path: 'dummy',
              loadChildren: () => import('../sample/sample.module').then(m => m.SamplePageModule)
            } ]
          },
          {
            path: 'tab2',
            loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
          },
          {
            path: 'tab3',
            loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
          },
          {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
            pathMatch: 'full'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ];
```

Here we have three tabs `tab1,tab2,tab3` and `dummy` is the child page of `tab1`

### tabsPage.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" **id="myTabs"**>
            ----
            ----
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

From your first tab you can navigate to child page navigate method. Since hiding tabs on inner pages is a known issue there is no straight forward method to hide it. So use the following custom method. Create a service class and add it as a common method

### ServiceClass

```
public toggleTabsBar(){
 const tabId = document.getElementById('myTabs');
    if (tabId) {
      if (tabId.style.display === 'none') {
        tabId.style.display = 'flex';
      }else{
        tabId.style.display = 'none'
      }
    }
}
```

In your child page here dummy page hide the tabs bar by invoking the `toggleTabsBar()` on `IonViewDidEnter()` method

### DummyPage

```
ionViewDidEnter(): void {
    this.toggleTabsBar();
  }
```

When you click the backbutton from the child page to navigate back to the parent page to show the tabs invoke the same method on the `IonViewDidEnter()` method.

Comment: Could you explain how conceptually you solve the problem? I'm having the same problem without tabs and can't deduce the solution from this response, which will only work with tabs. I'm using a menu.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are using {replaceUrl: true} when you navigate away from the component.